# Execute Methods until False

Tags: c#, testing

I have a list of methods I want to run through. In the event that any of them return false (fail), I want to do something that I haven't determined yet. //do something I'm looking for the trigger that will stop the remaining methods from firing. I know I can do a bunch of if statements but I was hoping to make it short, sweet, CLEAN.

I know this doesn't do what I'm expecting but it is how I would like things to look. Is there a way to make a foreach statement?

EDIT: To explain a little more, the while loop is the wrong way to go about it as I don't want to loop it. It was just the example of how I wanted to the code to look. I think what I'm looking for is a foreach loop but I cant figure out how to call each method from the foreach statement. The goal is that if one fails, its stops the rest from processing as the ones that follow are dependent on the one that failed. Thank you to the those that have helped so far.

````
        static void Main()
        {
            bool test = true;

            while (test != false) 
            {
                test = SomethingHere();
                test = SomethingElse();
                test = ShouldThrow();
                test = DidntCatch();
            }
        }
        static bool SomethingHere()
        {  return true; }
        static bool SomethingElse()
        { return true; }
        static bool ShouldThrow() 
        { return false; }
        static bool DidntCatch()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Didnt Catch");
            return false; 
        }```
````

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I'm afraid stack overflow isn't very beginner-friendly, although did you get answers. You can read [ask] in the [help] to get some information on how to ask questions here. I also advise you to take the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

You can join all conditions together with `&&`. If you *really* want to loop again and again:

```
while (SomethingHere() && SomethingElse() && ShouldThrow() && DidntCatch());
```

If you want to run tests just once:

```
if (SomethingHere() && SomethingElse() && ShouldThrow() && DidntCatch()) {
  // All tests pass
}
else {
  // At least one test fails 
}
```

Or (if number of tests can vary):

```
using System.Linq;

...

List<Func<bool>> tests = new() {
  SomethingHere, SomethingElse, ShouldThrow, DidntCatch
};

// Let's run tests once 
if (tests.All(f => f())) {
  // All tests passed
}
else {
  // At least one test failed
}
```

**Edit:** (See *JHBonarius* comment)

When combining tests we can use *two* operators: `&&` or `&`.

```
if (SomethingHere() & SomethingElse() & ShouldThrow() & DidntCatch()) {
  // All tests pass
}
```

The difference between `&&` and `&` is

- `&&` - *short-circuiting*: tests will be executed from left to right and if a test fails (returns `false`) all the rest will not be executed at all (having a failed test we know, that not all tests return `true`)
- `&` - all tests will be executed *regardless* to their results.

`All(f => f())` uses *short-circuiting*; if you want to ensure that *all* tests will be executed you can put it as

```
if (tests.Count(f => !f()) == 0) 
{
   // All tests are run, none of the failed
}
else 
{
   // Some tests failed
}
```

Comment: JHBonarius: Thank you! In case of testing it may be reasonable to run *all* tests regardless on their results (`&` operator).

Answer (score 2):

Can do something like this if you don't need to know which specific method failed.

```
if (SomethingHere() &&
    SomethingElse() &&
    ShouldThrow()   &&
    DidntCatch())
{
    // Everything passed
}
else
{
    // Something failed
}
```